# Difference between Disable and Toggle in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

Can you explain me please what is the difference between Disable and Toggle in Jmeter?

For example i got simple controller with few samplers or other components in it. I wanna know what it the difference between disabling or toggling this simple controller. From the first sight both of them are just turning it off, but i think there should be some difference

Comment: Please expand on your question.

Comment: @bc004346 updated question

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote.Thx

Answer (score 4):

Disable just disables.

Toggle can do both:

- If element is enabled it disables it
- If element is disabled it enables it

Answer (score 0):

**Enable/Disable**

If we select Enable or Disable its perform accordingly.

**Toggle**

If we select Toggle then it turn enabled to desable and disabled to enable.